# How do you lock X amount of monero for 200 blocks using the cli wallet?

Tags: monero-wallet-cli, transaction-unlock-time, cli

Using the monero cli wallet, what is the command and options to lock 10 monero for 200 blocks?

Comment: You're duplicating a question you previously asked, which is also a duplicate of another question.

Comment: Actually your right. I asked that awhile ago and totally forgot I did.

Comment: Well its good for SEO if someone is looking for these type of keywords when searching.

Comment: No. That is not how SE is supposed to be used. Users are encouraged to search for answers before asking. Duplicating questions in the hope of improving SEO is just a waste of everyones time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the **locked_transfer** command:

```
locked_transfer 4xxx... 10 200
```

It will look something like this:

[image]